# I am getting Runtime Error when I update ionic2 project to ionic3 ?

Tags: ionic-framework, npm, visual-studio-code, ionic3

**Runtime Error**
Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/.../src/constants/Strings.js.map' at Error (native)

typescript": "2.3.4"

**Ionic info**

global packages:

```
@ionic/cli-utils : 1.4.0
Cordova CLI      : 7.0.1
Ionic CLI        : 3.4.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts              : 1.3.7
@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova       : 1.4.0
@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular : 1.3.1
Cordova Platforms               : android 6.2.3 ios 4.4.0
Ionic Framework                 : ionic-angular 3.4.2
```

System:

```
Node       : v6.10.3
OS         : macOS Sierra
Xcode      : Xcode 8.3.2 Build version 8E2002
ios-deploy : 1.9.1
ios-sim    : 5.0.13
npm        : 5.0.3
```

Answer (score 0):

reading this [post](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/runtime-error-module-build-failed-error-enoent-no-such-file-or-directory/74356/6) on the official ionic blog it seems like it could be some import that are unmatched because capital letters.

Give it a try, hope this helps you to solve your problem.